# Need to insert events with existing attendees default ACCEPTED

Tags: google-calendar-api

Our CMS handles events for DJS, mostly weddings.  The client and DJ have already created the date and obviously the client has accepted.  When inserting a new event, setting responseStatus to accepted, the attendee (client) still receives a request to accept or decline.  This is causing a lot of confusion.

We simply need to generate and insert an event with attendees, already confirmed, with no action required on the attendee.

I've gone through the API and other help tutorials and created an object that handles the calendar.  When trying to set various items such as responseStatus:"Accepted" -- each and every time all attendees require action.  I just want the event to appear, no action required on any person.

Comment: Can you post the exact API call that you're making? I don't see any `responseStatus` in [the docs](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events), the field is called `status` and the value to accept it is `confirmed`.

Comment: status of confirmed is already set -- attendee still receives message